# Are auto-verified links cached in Android M?

Tags: android, caching, mobile, applinks, android-6.0-marshmallow

I'm currently working on running some tests to see how the verified links system works with Android M and ran into an interesting outcome. The usual flow is this:

- Install app
- GET to ${HOST}/.well-known/statements.json is fired
- If approved (server is up, key is valid, etc.), all verified links will deep link to app

When server is down, we see this

- Install app
- GET to ${HOST}/.well-known/statements.json is fired
- Not approved, links show pop-up
- Uninstall & reinstall app
- GET to ${HOST}/.well-known/statements.json is fired

However, if the server goes down after an initial verification, we see something interesting

- Install app
- GET to ${HOST}/.well-known/statements.json is fired
- Approved, deep links
- Turn off server
- Uninstall app & reinstall app
- **No network call made**

If we wait for some amount of time before reinstalling, then the network call is made and things act as normal. It seems like the autoverify data and/or app -> link data is being cached somewhere that isn't destroyed by app uninstall.

- Is this behavior expected?
- Why would this happen, versus always hitting the server?
- Where would this be cached, if not with the app?

Comment: Sorry I don't have any help to your problem but could you please explain to me how you're able to verify step #" - the GET request? Are you using your local computer as a proxy for the emulator?

Comment: Yes exactly! I'm using Charles proxy to verify the network calls.

Comment: Yes, it seems that app "com.android.statementservice" caches the link verification result.
Have you tried cleaning cache with "adb shell pm clear com.android.statementservice"?

Comment: Same thing is happening to me. Did you check if the fault was at your server end?